# how to output in JSON list in Apache thrift

Tags: java, json, output, thrift

I am currently using the following code:

```
TSerializer serializer = new TSerializer(
        new TJSONProtocol.Factory());

Log.print("[ \"rec\","+list.size()+",");
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if(i!=0) Log.print(",");
    Log.print(serializer
            .toString((TBase) (list.get(i))));
}
```

The list is a `ArrayList<RFileMetadata>()` data structure and I get the following output for example:

```
[
    "rec",
    3,
    {
        "1": {
            "str": "allalla"
        },
        "2": {
            "i64": 91299230
        }
    },
    {
        "1": {
            "str": "allalla"
        },
        "2": {
            "i64": 91299230
        }
    },
    {
        "1": {
            "str": "allalla"
        },
        "2": {
            "i64": 91299230
        }
    }
]
```

But how can I output it directly.

I am asking a code which doesnt use the for loop to manually print the `["rec",3,....]` and so on .I shouldnt generate, the program should generate it for me.

Comment: It's hard to say from your text what you really want. If you want to have a piece of code that produces the output above, you basically have to do what the Thrift code is doing. Should not be that hard to find out from the sources. What's completely unclear is to me is the last sentence "I shouldnt generate, the program should generate it for me" - what exactly is "it"? The output? The code that generates the output? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to explicitly create a json string and then stringify that.
Apache thrift provide a better way to do it.

If you go through the code of your `FileStore` it is named as same on my thrift local.

```
List<RFileMetadata> struct = client.listOwnedFiles(userName);

jsonProtocol.writeListBegin(new org.apache.thrift.protocol.TList(org.apache.thrift.protocol.TType.STRUCT, struct.size()));

   for (RFileMetadata _iter3 : struct) {
         _iter3.write(jsonProtocol);
    }

jsonProtocol.writeListEnd();
```

If you explore more thrift code it will be easier for you to understand how thrift actually works.